# Excel vba code to run command line works only when breakpoint is added

Tags: batch-file, excel, vba

Basically I have a batchfile that I am running using the runcmd function in excel vba

```
Function runCmd(fileCommand As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Hnd
    Dim strCmdPath As String
    strCmdPath = VBA.Environ$("COMSPEC")
    VBA.ChDir "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\"
    VBA.Shell strCmdPath & " /c" & fileCommand, vbNormalFocus
    runCmd = True
Exit Function
Err_Hnd:
    runCmd = False
End Function
```

The filecommand is the full path of the batch file. When I run this code, I get the following error

*'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Move.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

However when I place a break point on the line **runCmd = True** and use F8 or F5 to run the code it works perfectly. No idea why this is happening.

EDIT: After trying  ChrisProsser's code I got a slightly different error. 
The cmd prompt said -

*1 dir(s) was moved. Could not find batch file.*

It only moved 1 folder.

Unfortunately this is not verbatim since I could not recreate this error again and did not note down the error the first time.

So some more info  - The batch file is actually a text file which contains the move code which is converted to batch file during runtime and back to text file after this function runCmd is executed. 
Hence the process is

- textfile to batchfile
- runCmd batchfile
- batchfile to textfile

Could this cause and error?

Comment: Please can you give an example of the fileCommand parameter you call runCmd with, is it a relative path from your user profile?

Comment: 'C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Move.bat' is the fileCommand parameter. 
It is the complete path of the batch file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this would work when stepping through, but not if executed in one go, but I would try adding a step to set your command string then execute it e.g.

```
Function runCmd(fileCommand As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err_Hnd
    Dim strCmdPath As String
    Dim strCmd as String
    strCmdPath = VBA.Environ$("COMSPEC")
    VBA.ChDir "C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\"
    strCmd  =  strCmdPath & " /c" & fileCommand, vbNormalFocus
    VBA.Shell strCmd
    runCmd = True
Exit Function
Err_Hnd:
    runCmd = False
End Function
```

Comment: It seems like a good idea. But unfortunately this does not fix the problem.

Comment: I added some edits may be that could help in getting the solution.

Comment: What is the logic behind storing the batch command in a text file file rather than a .cmd or.bat file? To see if this is the issue you can just rename the file to .cmd and try it. If this doesn't work then output the value of strCmd to the immediate window using debug.print and see whether you can run this command successfully from cmd.

Comment: Actually the input is a text file which contains all the commands. Instead of looping through the commands in the file, I am saving it as a batch file and then am running the code. I have done the following
a. Just run the batch file directly by double clicking it - This works
b. Run individual commands in the command prompt. That works as well
c. Copy paste all the commands into command prompt. This too works.

Not sure what the problem is.